# хранение и чтение локальных файлов

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

День добрый! 
Подскажите как организовать что-то типа локальной БД. 
Нужно с локального сайта получать содержимое локальных файлов из того же каталога. Есть какое-нибудь рабочее решение? Прочитать json без локального сервера не получилось, а других решений не придумал. Как можно хранить информацию и как ее считать?

Comment: Из браузера читать фс?

Comment: У вас вопрос в том, как записать информацию на клиенте, а потом считать или как прочитать файл на клиенте?

Comment: По сути - как прочитать данные из локального файла без сервера. Json почитать не получилось, так что спрашиваю в вам еще можно хранить данные и как их читать на страницу в браузер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через браузер не как, без сервера (например [Open Server Panel](https://ospanel.io/)). Но есть решение типа [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/). Конечно нужно почитать, быстро не получится. За то получите полноценное приложение.